# Description of dependencies in requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip

I've been given a large `requirements.txt` file with ~130 dependencies, half of which I don't recognise.

Is there an easy way to get a short desciption of each dependency without having to look each one up myself in the [CheeseShop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShop)?

Comment: pip show <module> or pip show <module1>, <module2>, ...

Comment: @정도유 `pip show` doesn't work for me, I think because I don't actually have these dependencies installed. I guess I could install them in a virtualenv and then delete the virtualenv if that's the easiest solution

Comment: Download them without dependencies with `pip download --no-deps -r requirements.txt` and look into every archive.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can get `info` (including a `summary` and the latest `version`) directly from pypi.org as JSON:

`http://pypi.org/pypi/<package_name>/json`

This is working for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
import sys
from urllib import request
from urllib.error import HTTPError

filename = 'requirements.txt' if len(sys.argv) == 1 else sys.argv[1]

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        package = line.split('=', 1)[0].rstrip()
        # remove any version info given after '>' or '<'
        package = package.split('<')[0].split('>')[0]

        if not package: continue

        url = 'https://pypi.org/pypi/{}/json'.format(package)
        try:
            with request.urlopen(url.format(package)) as url:
                data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
                summary = data['info']['summary']
                version = data['info']['version']
        except:  # e.g. HTTPError:
            summary = 'error'
            version = ''

        print('{} ({}): {}'.format(line.rstrip(), version, summary))
```